# How to compare two divs for same number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to compare two divs for the same number then do something

I am using .is function

```
jQuery(function ($) { 

  if ( $("#result").is(".count-entries") ) {
    alert("true");
  } 

});


<div class="count-entries">2</div>
<div id="result">2</div>
```

The alert isn't firing when the numbers are the same in the divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if 2 divs have the same content, you can get the text of the div using `text()`, use `trim()` to remove extra spaces.

**Note:** `.count-entries` is a class, there could be multiple elements with this class. You might need to specify the `id` if that is the case.

```js
if ($("#result").text().trim() === $(".count-entries").text().trim()) {
  console.log("Content is the same");
} else {
  console.log("Content is not the same");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count-entries">2</div>
<div id="result">2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking of checking the `.text()` of the divs, to see if they match.

```
if ($("#result").text() == $("count-entries").text()) {
    alert("true");
};
```

Checking the actual content is not a good way of checking values, as any function which gets that info, returns the contents as a string, and if any space characters are included in only one of the two, the strings will not be equal, and it would not evaluate to true.

Give more info about your use case, and we will be able to provide better guidance.

Comment: `$("#result")` will return a jQuery object. And it will not have any property called `innerHTML`. Use `html()` if you want to innerHTML of jquery object.

Comment: fair enough. updating at once. much thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(function () { 

     var entries=$(".count-entries").val(); /*To get the value*/
     var result=$("#result").val();

      if ( entries==result ) {
        alert("true");
      } 
    });

     <div class="count-entries">2</div>
     <div id="result">2</div>
```

:D